# How to draw a graph with different shades of color based on the values of the data, but with a different color tone for each column in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly, heatmap

Now I have a matrix data of size 5*4, but the values of different columns of the matrix are uncorrelated.

```
matrix = [[1.1  2.5  32.3  14.  ]
 [1.5  2.6  38.7  54.8 ]
 [1.9  2.1  13.11 46.12]
 [1.13 2.14 35.15 48.16]
 [1.17 2.18 27.19 74.2 ]]
```

Now I want to use color blocks to represent the size of the matrix values, but each column has a different color tone. The effect is like this image below, you can see that the tone of the first column is blue, the second is red, every column just in different shades:

[image]

Hope I made myself clear, thanks!

Comment: can you provide a sample matrix?

Comment: Okay, I reedited the question @mozway

Comment: I find this answer at plotly community to be very helpful. [Custom Colormap. How to specify coloraa](https://community.plotly.com/t/custom-colormap-how-to-specify-coloraa/50975) and [https://chart-studio.plotly.com/~empet/15229/heatmap-with-a-discrete-colorscale/#/](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/~empet/15229/heatmap-with-a-discrete-colorscale/#/)

Answer (score 1):

You can plot a heatmap for each of your columns separately. Be sure to put the colormaps of your choice in a list (use `itertools.cycle` for variable matrix size):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

matrix = np.random.rand(7, 7)
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)

ncols = len(df.columns)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=ncols)

# no space between columns
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

# put colormaps of your choice in a list:
cmap_cycle = cycle(['Greens', 'Reds', 'Blues', 'Oranges', 'Purples'])

for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, i]), cbar=False, ax=ax, cmap=cmap_cycle.__next__(), xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Edit: you can play with kwargs `vmin` and `vmax` to avoid white cells (see https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)

Comment: thanks!it perfectly solved my problem

Comment: Great! would you consider accepting the answer?